# Warning: implicit declaration of function ‘vasprintf’?

Tags: c, linux

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static int mylog(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char *str = NULL;

    va_start(args, format);
    vasprintf(&str, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    fprintf(stdout, "Test >> %s", str);

    free(str);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //...
}
```

`warning: implicit declaration of function ‘vasprintf’; did you mean ‘vsprintf’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Why is the compiler issuing a warning for `vasprintf`?

`gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)`

Comment: Please show your build command.

Comment: Well, what can you tell us more about your environment? What compiler options are you using? Are you using ubuntu? What glibc version are you using? Are you compiling in any virtualized environment? Does a smaller file like `#define _GNU_SOURCE #include <stdio.h> int main() { va_list a; vasprintf(0, "", a); }`  also shows the message when compiling? Could you show the output of `gcc -v ....` verbose compilation command? Does `cpp -D_GNU_SOURCE /usr/include/stdio.h | grep vasprintf` output anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable the Dynamic Allocation Functions, features from ISO/IEC TR 24731-2:2010, you have to define the macro `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__` to `1` before to include the `stdio.h` header:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ 1  //Define you want TR 24731-2:2010 extensions
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static int mylog(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char *str = NULL;

    va_start(args, format);
    vasprintf(&str, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    fprintf(stdout, "Test >> %s", str);

    free(str);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //...
}
```

Note that these extensions are optional, GCC doesn't implements all of them, and other compilers can implement different set.